# Divisibility of $\frac{2^k-a_n}{3^n}$ for all primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem is proving whether $2^k-a_n = 0 \pmod u$, $2^k-a_n = 0\pmod {3^n}$ for a sequence $a_n$ defined $a_{n+1}= 2a_n +3^n$ and $a_1 = 1$, can be solved for any $u$ (Such that u is the biggest number possible so $2^k-a_n = 0 \pmod u$) . I thought that it would be best to start with a prime $u$, but I haven't found any better approaches than just trial and error. This only solved the problem for specific cases but not generally.

This is my first question, so please give feedback on the quality of the question and how I can improve it. Thanks!

Edit: I checked my answer for the base case $a_1 = 1$ and have found that sometimes random prime factors divide $ 2^k -1$ and after looking at the pattern of these factors, I predict that any factors for a prime k will be of the form $2^V *k -1$ if $2^k -1$ itself t isn’t already prime. The problem is finding what values of u in general this covers, and u is the product of all those prime factors so it is hard to generalize.

Edit2: changed u to be the biggest possible number in that case. This is what I originally meant but forgot to add to the problem.

Edit 3: edit 1(for $2^2k +1$ (2k temporarily replacing k) does give U= Gcd((2k+1),$(2^k-1)$) but I don’t know how to prove edit 1 completely.(this is for a prime 2k + 1)

Clarification 1: to make this clearer, I’m trying to find weather we can get any intiger number u we want that divides $2^k-a_n$ The new answer below helps construct any u =$ 3^{something}$ but can it take other values??From my work above, it seems that for any number of the form $2^k -1$ where a prime 2k+1 divides it, it is possible though a proof of this would be hard. (Would need to prove that any factors of $2^k -1$ you can’t just get from eulers generalization of fermats little theorem, would be given by 2k +1 (or maybe $2^{an odd number}$ *k + 1)

Clarification 2: you can choose your k and n to see what values you can get out of u instead of oroving values for all n (which is crazy and I never knew was possible to prove) (I asked for “all primes” in the title, because if we can isolate primes in this way then using edits seen above we probably can for all other intigers too)

Comment: To format $n+1$ as a subscript (or anything that is more than one symbol) simply surround it with curly brackets. For example, \$a_{n+1}\$ renders $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: It looks like you may have fixed it for me in the question. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Also, props to you for asking for feedback.

Comment: 1/ What is $k$? Is that something you can choose IE Find a $k$ such that ...  2) Why is there $3^n$ in the denominator? It doesn't affect if $2^k - a_n \equiv 0 \pmod{u}$, except when $u = 3$. 3) Can you show your work for a particular prime $u$, esp if you've solved it for certain specific cases.

Comment: 1. K is something that can be chosen and even just one k getting a u to work would mean that u works.  2.That 3 ^n is just to make sure that 2^k -a_n = 0 (mod 3^k ) as well, but it might make more sense for that to be a separate condition. I will fix that. 3. I got it to work for all primes 1(mod 4) for n= 1 (as detailed above)

Comment: So you want to know if there is a $k$ for each $n?$ Or one $k$ for all $n?$

Comment: Writing $a_n$ explicitly, it is $a_n=3^n-2^n$.

Comment: One or multiple values of k per value of n

Comment: Oh that closed form for $a_n$ is very helpful. Thanks!!!

Comment: So for a given $n$, you want to find the set of $u$ such that there is some $k$ such that $2^k-a_n$ is a multiple of both $u$ and $3^k$? Also I don't know if this is what you intended, but you changed it from dividing $2^k-a_n$ by $3^n$ to seeing if it's divisible by $3^k$ (I think $k$ to $n$ changes it).

Comment: Yhea it was meant to be 3^n and basically what you said but if the union  set of u for all n cover all the primes (or intigers)

Comment: Hint: $a_n=3^n-2^n$

Comment: What does $\pmod {3^n}\pmod u$ mean?

Comment: It satisfies both 0 (mod $3^n) and mod u I’ll clear that up in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, we make the following claim:

**THM 1:** *Let $n$ be any positive integer and let $a$ be any integer satisfying $(3,a)=1$ i.e., $a$ does not have to be prime. Then there is an integer $k$ such that $3^n|(2^k-a)$.*

Note that THM 1 establishes all you need; $a$ does not have to be prime; instead $a$ has to just be any integer satisfying $(a,3)=1$. [Note that for $3^n$ [with $n \ge 1$] to divide $(2^k-a)$ that $a$ cannot be a multiple of $3$ so this covers everything.] To establish THM 1, use induction on $n$ to show the following.

**Lemma 2:** *The integer $2$ is primitive in $(\mathbb{Z}/3^n\mathbb{Z})^*$, i.e., every element $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/3^n\mathbb{Z})^*$ can be written $a \equiv_{3^n} 2^k$ for some positive integer $k$. Eqivalently, $2$ generates the entire group $(\mathbb{Z}/3^n\mathbb{Z})^*$.*

*SKETCH OF PROOF OF Lemma 2:* Note that both $|(\mathbb{Z}/3^n\mathbb{Z})^*| =2\times 3^{n-1}$ and $2^a \equiv_3 2 \not = 1$ for any *odd* positive integer $a$, so the smallest *positive* integer $k$ satisfying $2^k \equiv_{3^n} 1$ must satisfy $k=2 \times 3^{m}$; $m$ a nonnegative integer satisfying $m<n$. So we now use induction as claimed; assume that $n \ge 4$ and that the following is true:
$$2^{2 \times 3^{n-2}} \not \equiv_{3^n} 1.$$ [This can be checked directly for $n=2,3,4$.]
Then to establish Lemma 2, it suffices to show that the following is also true:
$$2^{2 \times 3^{n-1}} \not \equiv_{3^{n+1}} 1.$$ [Make sure you see why this is.] However,
$$2^{2 \times 3^{n-2}} \not \equiv_{3^n} 1$$
$$\implies {\text{ there is an integer $c$}}$$ $${\text{satisfying $(c,3)=1$ s.t. }}$$ $$2^{2 \times 3^{n-2}} = 1 + \Big(c \times 3^{n-1}\Big)$$
$$\implies 2^{2 \times 3^{n-1}} = \Big(2^{2 \times 3^{n-2}}\Big)^3$$ $$= \Big(1 + \Big(c \times 3^{n-1}\Big)\Big)^3$$ $$=1 + 3\Big(c \times 3^{n-1}\Big) + \Big(C×3^{2n-2}\Big)$$ $$\text{for some integer $C$}$$
$$\implies 2^{2 \times 3^{n-1}} \not \equiv_{3^{n+1}} 1,$$
which is what we wanted. $\surd$

Then THM 1 follows immediately from Lemma 2. Indeed, pick a positive integer $k$ such that $2^k \equiv_{3^n} a$; as $2$ generates every element in $(\mathbb{Z}/3^n \mathbb{Z})^*$ and $(3,a)=1$, there is indeed a positive integer $k$ such that $2^k \equiv_{3^n} a$. So THM 1 indeed follows. $\surd$

**ETA:** The conclusion of THM 1 hinges on $2$ generating the entire group $(\mathbb{Z}/3^n\mathbb{Z})^*$. There are primes $q$ [namely, $q=7$ and $q=17$ are such primes] for which
$2$ does not generate the entire group $(\mathbb{Z}/q^n\mathbb{Z})^*$. So let $q$ be such a prime and let $a \in$ $(\mathbb{Z}/q^n\mathbb{Z})^*$ such that $a$ is not generated by $2$. Then there is no integer $k$ such that $q^n$ divides $2^k-a$.

If, to elaborate, we were to replace $3$ by $17$ [or any other odd prime $q$ for which $2$ is a square in $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^*$], and take $a$ any nonsquare in $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^*$, then there is no integer $k$ such that $q$ divides $2^k-a$, nevermind $q^n$ dividing $2^k-a$ for any other positive integer $n$. For example, there is no integer $k$ such that $17$ divides $2^k-12$. Indeed, $2$ is a square in $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*$, and so $2^k$  is a square in $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*$ for all integers $k$, whereas $12$ is not a square in $(\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z})^*$. So even for $n=1$, there is no integer $k$ such that $2^k \equiv_{17} 12$, nevermind higher powers of $17$.

Similarly, there is no integer $k$ such that $7$ divides $2^k-5$, nevermind $7^n$ dividing $2^k-5$ for general positive integers $n$.

Comment: This answers a pretty huge part of the question, but if it is meant to answer the whole question then u is not addressed.

Comment: @SunniestWheat38. I editted my answer. This--what I had before, however, answers the question as originally stated. It is on the person asking to be clear and explicit in what they are asking, *the first time* they posted, please, as people put time and thought into answering.

Comment: Ok, i am really sorry about that. I will be clear and explicit the next time I post.That really is on me.

Comment: No worries @SunniestWheat38 this was a fun problem to work on, thank you for posting!